# Laravel 5 error while installing package

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

When i was upgrading from laravel 4.2 to laravel 5 i got this error while installing packages from composer

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Config\Repository::package()
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem is because the package you're trying to use has not yet been updated to work with Laravel 5.

There is no work around or fix, you must wait for the package to be updated, or fork it and submit a PR

Answer (score 0):

add this to your composer.json

"require": {
  "laravel/framework": "dev-master#846c935194a036901ba6b4397c8897fa51e19111",
   ...
}

for more information see link below:

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/l5-latest-commit-breaks-if-using-waygenerators-or-image-internvention

Comment: This was a bad fix whilst L5 was in development. L5 has now been released and the package OP is trying to use hasn't been updated. Reverting to this commit would mean a lot of features from L5 will not be present and just leave a horrible mess. Not only that it would mean no updates to L5 will be received, which could be important security fixes.